# Definition of the term "basis of kernel" of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Conceptually and abstractly speaking, what is the "basis of kernel" of a matrix?

Comment: The kernel of a linear transformation is a vector space.  Do you know the concept "basis of a vector space"?  Do you know how a matrix corresponds to a linear transofrmation?

Comment: What is a basis? I do not know basis. I know kernel. What is a vector space? In know that a matrix corresponds to a linear transformation.

Comment: You will first need to learn "basis of a vector space" and then you will be able to understand "basis of kernel".

Comment: Have you done any research on this question, perhaps by Googling the key terms of your question?

Comment: Basis of kernel of a matrix $A$ is the maximal linearly independent subset of the kernel of $A$ that generates the kernel of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of a matrix $M$ is the set of vectors $x$ such that:
$$
Mx=0
$$
if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are elements of the kernel, by linearity, we can see that:
$$M(ax_1+bx_2)=aMx_1+bMx_2=0$$, so the kernel is a vector space and, as all vector spaces  have  a basis, there is a basis for the kernel, that is a set of linearly independent vectors such that any vector of the kernel can be expressed as a linear combination of them, and the number of such linear independent vectors is the **dimension** of the kernel.